# Where does the Haskell function `seq` get its name from?

Tags: haskell

I get that `seq` is used to improve performance by avoiding unneeded laziness. I just want to know where the name is derived from? Is it from "sequence" or "sequential"? And how does the name relate to strict evaluation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It comes from [sequence point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point). That's a well-known concept in C, and it's indeed quite similar to the `seq` operator in Haskell: *every computation on the left should be done before any computation on the right*.

Of course, Haskell `seq` is a bit less demanding than that: it merely requests that the thing on the left is evaluated to *weak head normal form* before the result on the right is evaluated. And it doesn't really *guarantee* any particular evaluation order at all<sup>†</sup>, only that if the expression on the left is ⊥ then the one on the right must not be evaluated.

See [`pseq`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/GHC-Conc.html#v:pseq) or [`deepseq`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/deepseq-1.4.4.0/docs/Control-DeepSeq.html#v:deepseq) for stronger alternatives, which come closer to what C calls sequence points.

---

<sup>†</sup><sub>Actually, C or C++ sequence points don't guarantee computation order either, only that any *side effects* are in the right order. But, in C side effects are ubiquitous so apart from low-level optimisations you *can* usually assume that sequence-point order will be upheld, whereas GHC will in fact quite often throw `seq`s away if only it knows that the expressions do not diverge.</sub>

Comment: I don't think that "if the expression on the left is ⊥ then the one on the right must not be evaluated." See https://wiki.haskell.org/Seq, for instance, where it says a lawful implementation of `seq a b` would be: "evaluate `b`, then `a`, then return `b`".

Comment: @oisdk well, it doesn't really make sense to talk about _evaluation_ at all – this isn't even a defined notion. The point is, if `a` is ⊥ then ``a `seq` b`` must not give back the result of `b`.

Comment: By "evaluate" I mean "force to weak head normal form". Also, I still think that your explanation isn't correct: you could give back the result of `b` if it was `⊥`. I think saying that you're guaranteeing `b` won't be "evaluated" (or looked at) in any sense is misleading, and even practically wrong (and I think it's the central difference with `pseq`). I think "forcing the result of `seq a b` necessarily forces `a`, and `seq a b = b` when `a != ⊥`" is more accurate.

Comment: @oisdk but “forcing” isn't anything Haskell knows about. – Yes, theoretically you could “give back the result of `b` if it was `⊥`” – that would be something that makes at least sense to say, in Haskell without referring to any implementation. Only, you couldn't _actually_ do this, in general – because it would require first _proving_ that `b` is `⊥`, and for that you need to solve tha halting problem.

Comment: Sure, "forcing" isn't a term you can use to describe the semantics, but neither is "evaluate", and I'm trying to present an alternative to the two explanations you gave: "the thing on the left is evaluated to weak head normal form before the result on the right is evaluated", "if the expression on the left is ⊥ then the one on the right must not be evaluated", both of which I think are wrong. For a precise explanation, I would say "`seq a b = b` when `a != ⊥`", and then to describe how it actually tends to work in GHC, I would say "forcing the result of `seq a b` necessarily forces `a`".

Comment: I just think that your explanations erroneously mention order and "not evaluating `b`", neither of which is guaranteed by `seq` in theory or practice. (also I should have said "`seq a b = ⊥` when `a = ⊥`, `seq a b = b` otherwise". for the precise explanation)

Comment: An alternate explanation can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61479290/why-is-the-strictness-introducing-function-called-seq .