# Why is the strictness-introducing function called seq?

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation

I understand the [seq](https://wiki.haskell.org/Seq) function and why it's necessary to introduce strictness for efficiency. What I don't understand is, why is this primitive called `seq` (and not something to do with strictness)?

Comment: I guess it comes from "sequence" as in "evaluate this before evaluating that". If this is the origin, it's a very misleading name, since it does _not_ guarantee that the first argument is evaluated before the other.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TL;DR: Miranda called it `seq`, it was introduced when `sequence` was (probably) already a thing for Monads, and `($!)` was known as `strict` for a short time.

## Miranda was first

It is called `seq` because it was called `seq` in [Miranda](https://www.haskell.org/definition/from12to13.html#monad) and previous languages, at least according to [*A History of Haskell: Being Lazy With Class* by Paul Hudak, John Hughes, Simon Peyton Jones and Philip Wadler](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/1238844.1238856).

> Both `seq` and strict components of data structures were  already  present  in  Miranda  for  the  same  reasons  (Turner, 1985),  and  indeed `seq` had  been  used  to  fix  space  leaks  in  lazy programs since the early 1980s (Scheevel, 1984; Hughes, 1983)

Note that [Turner only introduced the strict components in the 1985 paper](https://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/people/staff/dat/miranda/nancypaper.pdf), not `seq` itself, and Scheevel's "NORMA Sasl manual" seems to be lost or at least not available on the Internet. Hughes thesis ("Hughes, 1983" above) doesn't introduce `seq` either.

Either way, [`seq` was part of Mirandas standard environment](https://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/people/staff/dat/miranda/stdenv.html) and also contains a hint why it was called `seq`:

> `seq' applied to two values, returns the second but checks that the first value is not completely undefined. Sometimes needed, e.g. to ensure correct synchronisation in interactive programs.

Correct synchronisation or **seq**uencing.

## Other possible names

Now, why wasn't that simply called `strict` in Haskell? Or even `sequence`?

Well, it turns out that [Haskell 1.3](https://www.haskell.org/definition/from12to13.html), which introduced `seq`, did also introduce `Monad`, and thus `sequence :: Monad m => [m a] -> m ()`. Therefore, `sequence` was not available as a name.

Now that `sequence` was out of the picture, let's have a look at `strict`. `strict` was included in 1.3, since 1.3 [introduced an `Eval` typeclass](https://www.haskell.org/definition/from12to13.html#strict):

```
seq :: Eval a => a -> b -> b
strict :: Eval a => (a -> b) -> (a -> b)
strict f = \x -> seq x (f x)
```

Neither `Eval` nor `strict` didn't make the cut into Haskell98 as-is. Instead, `Eval` was completely removed, as it applied to all types either way, and `strict` was renamed to `($!)`.

Comment: Note: I rewrote this answer multiple times from scratch whenever I came across a new source that shined a little bit more light on the topic. Also note that you will lose pare of your sanity if you try to run the old Haskell versions 1.0 and 1.1 through a modern LaTeX environment. Luckily, none of 1.0, 1.1 nor 1.2 included `seq`, and 1.3 has a proper `.ps` and HTML release at hand. If you want to see why monadic I/O was celebrated then look up the old `[Request] -> [Response]` based IO model. *Being Lazy With Class* probably is the best resource to look further, aside from old meeting minutes.

Comment: As to why `seq` in Haskell isn't actually sequential, unlike its counterparts in earlier languages - you may find the mail thread *seq vs. pseq* informative, starting with https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/glasgow-haskell-users/2006-November/011480.html . GHC issue [#5129](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/issues/5129) could also be helpful.